# how to check if a variable contains int data and not float

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variables, integer

so I need a program that checks if a variable is integer and it's not float data.

I tried this:

```
var = 2.5
if var is int :
    print(var)
else :
    pass
```

but this didn't work. can you help me on this? thanks.

Answer (score 6):

you can use simply the [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) check

```
if isinstance(tocheck,int):
    print("is an int!")
elif isinstance(tocheck,float):
    print("is a float")
else:
    print("is not int and is not float!")
```

you could also use the [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) function but it doesn't check for subclasses so it's not recommended but provide anyways:

```
if type(x)==int:
    print("x is int")
elif type(x)==float:
    print("x is float")
else:
    print("x is neither float or int")
```

here are some useful links

- [programiz isinstance](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/isinstance)
- [w3schools isinstance](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_isinstance.asp)
- [isinstance official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)
- [type vs isinstance stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `isinstance()` function:

```
if isinstance(var, int):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the type method

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/type

```
print(type(var))
```

or

```
var = 2.5
if type(var) is int :
    print(var)
else :
    pass
```

Comment: 1) type is not a method, is a function. 2) type(x) is not reccomended since it doesn't support subclass checks

Answer (score -1):

you can user type() here.

for example :

var = 2.5
if type(var) is int :
print(var)
else :
pass

Comment: Your code appears to be an exact copy of the code in the question, without formatting.